# torchvision.datasets.mnist RunTimeError on JupyterLab

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pytorch, jupyter-lab, mnist, torchvision

I'm trying to run the following sample code on JupyterLab (through GCP vertex AI):

```
import torch
from torchvision import transforms
from torchvision import datasets

train_data = datasets.MNIST(root='data', train=True, download=True, transform=None)
print(train_data)
```

with versions:
torch-1.12.1+cu113
torchvision-0.13.1+cu113

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_10081/229378695.py in <module>
     11 from torchvision import datasets
     12 
---> 13 train_data = datasets.MNIST(root='data', train=True, download=True, transform=None)
     14 print(train_data)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/mnist.py in __init__(self, root, train, transform, target_transform, download)
    102             raise RuntimeError("Dataset not found. You can use download=True to download it")
    103 
--> 104         self.data, self.targets = self._load_data()
    105 
    106     def _check_legacy_exist(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/mnist.py in _load_data(self)
    121     def _load_data(self):
    122         image_file = f"{'train' if self.train else 't10k'}-images-idx3-ubyte"
--> 123         data = read_image_file(os.path.join(self.raw_folder, image_file))
    124 
    125         label_file = f"{'train' if self.train else 't10k'}-labels-idx1-ubyte"

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/mnist.py in read_image_file(path)
    542 
    543 def read_image_file(path: str) -> torch.Tensor:
--> 544     x = read_sn3_pascalvincent_tensor(path, strict=False)
    545     if x.dtype != torch.uint8:
    546         raise TypeError(f"x should be of dtype torch.uint8 instead of {x.dtype}")

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/mnist.py in read_sn3_pascalvincent_tensor(path, strict)
    529 
    530     assert parsed.shape[0] == np.prod(s) or not strict
--> 531     return parsed.view(*s)
    532 
    533 

RuntimeError: shape '[60000, 28, 28]' is invalid for input of size 9437168
____________________
```

and I'm getting this strange error when trying to load MNIST

- I tried reproducing it in other envaironments but couldn't - it works great locally & on cloab
- I tried lots of other versions of torch and torchvision but non of them works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is often caused by an issue with the MNIST dataset files that are downloaded onto your system. Try deleting the MNIST dataset files in the `data` directory and then running the code again to download fresh copies of the dataset files. Follow this code:

```py
import os
import shutil

mnist_folder = 'data/MNIST'
if os.path.exists(mnist_folder):
    shutil.rmtree(mnist_folder)

train_data = datasets.MNIST(root='data', train=True, download=True, transform=None)
```

If this method doesn't work, visit [this website](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) and placing them in the `data/MNIST` folder.